# How get current time and assign to float variable in python

Tags: python-2.7

I want to get current time and assign it to float variable.And also it should be infinite loop. Here is my code , but it is not working.

```
import time
while(1==1):
    float a = time.strftime("%H:%M")
    print a
```

Comment: Why is it not working? What is the current vs expected output?

Comment: I want to print the time (What is in my computer now)

Comment: Start simple. No need for a loop until after you can get it to work once. In Python, that's not how you set variables. See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html

Comment: There is an error in this line                                                                    float a = time.strftime("%H:%M")

Comment: As what Dan said. Use `a = time.strftime("%H:%M")`. Next time show an error message to make things clearer.

Comment: If you're not doing anything with `a` why don't you just print the time directly? Also why do you care that it's a float?

Answer (score 0):

`import time
while(True):
    a = float(time.strftime("%H.%M"))
    print a`

Here you cannot use ':', because then the resultant string would be like '11:07', which can not be converted to float. You'll have to format time as "%H.%M".